# how can I print a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, char

I am working on a simple hotel reservsation Project but I couldn't print the customer name and payment type after entering their names'. Here is the piece of code that I typed.

```
 cout << "Please enter the customer name: " << endl;
 cin >> customername1;
 cin.getline(customername1,100,'\n');
 fflush(stdin);
 cout << "Please enter the payment type: " << endl;
 cin >> paymenttype;
 cin.getline(paymenttype,100,'\n');
 fflush(stdin);
 cout << "How many days would you like to stay: " << endl;
 cin >> days;
 room_income = days * 30;
 count_room++ ;
 count_customer1++ ;
 customer_name1[single]= new char [strlen(customername1)+1]; 
 strcpy(customer_name1[single],customername1); 
 payment_type[single]= new char [strlen(paymenttype)+1]; 
 strcpy(payment_type[single],paymenttype);
 cout << "Room number : " << single << endl<< endl;
 cout << "Customer name : "<< customer_name1 << endl << endl;
 cout << "Payment type : "<< payment_type << endl<< endl;
 cout << "Number of day for accomodation :"<< days << endl<< endl;
 cout << "Income for this room : "<< room_income<< endl<< endl;
```

Some random numbers and letters are displayed for the customer name and payment type. How can I write them properly?

Comment: What is the type of say `customername1`? Why are reading it twice? (`>>` and `getline`)

Comment: `new char [strlen(customername1)+1];` wooooah there! How about a nice game of `std::string` instead?

Comment: `cin >> customername1;` already reads the input, why are you doing `cin.getline(customername1,100,'\n');` afterwards??

Comment: Yes you're right guys. Problem fixed. cin.getline(customername1,100,'\n');  is useless. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the customer name and payment type, you try to print the array, instead of one element. Since the array is basically just a pointer to the first element, you will get a 'random number', which is the memory address.

Try:

```
cout << "Customer name : "<< customername1 << endl << endl;
cout << "Payment type : "<< paymenttype << endl<< endl;
```

And when you've got that working, follow the comments and look into std::string and vectors...

Comment: Yes you're right and  also I think cin.getline(customername1,100,'\n') is unnecessary

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, look closely at the names of the variables... OP, you are right about your comment.

Comment: Good call.  Pesky little underscores.